# How can I use switchMap instead of nested subscriptions?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-material, angular2-observables

I'm still learning observables, so I won't be surprised if there's an easy solution. Basically what I have right now is four nested subscriptions with a fourEach inside the second subscribe(). I saw lots of answers using switchMap, but I couldn't find one that also had a for loop to iterate through. I know I probably should be using nested subscriptions, but I can't figure out how to do it with the forEach.

This is the working code with the nested subscribes:

```
dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
  if(result) {
    this.createLikertResponseGroup(result.likertResponseGroup)
      .subscribe(likertResponseGroupJSON => {

        result.likertResponse.controls.likertResponseFormArray.controls.forEach((element) => {
          let characteristic = element.controls.characteristic;
          this.newResponseGroupId = likertResponseGroupJSON.LikertResponseGroup.id;

          this.createLikertResponse(element, this.newResponseGroupId)
            .subscribe(likertResponseJSON => {

              if (characteristic) {
                let responseId = likertResponseJSON.LikertResponse.id;

                this.createCharacteristic(characteristic, this.newResponseGroupId, responseId)
                  .subscribe(characteristicJSON => {
                    this.newCharacteristicId = characteristicJSON.Characteristic.id;
                  });
              }
            });
        });
      })
  }
});
```

What I have works right now. So my question is, is it worth changing how I'm doing this? If so, how would I go about it?

I haven't gotten far, but my attempt with switchMap looks like this:

```
dialogRef.afterClosed().pipe(
  filter(result => result != null),
  switchMap(result => 
    from(result.likertResponse.controls.likertResponseFormArray.controls).pipe(
      // not sure what to do after this (or if I'm even doing it right)
    )
  ),
);
```

Comment: The idea for using switch map, is that the first "observable part" should _return_ a new observable, instead of subscribing to a new observable. `switchMap` will do the glue between them, and basically replace `subscribe` by "finish the first subscribe and switchmap to another". Now, in your first case, you have a `if` and two cases. So, if you want to use switchmap, you must return an observable in both cases. In the case where you want to do nothing, you can return `Observable.empty`. In your normal case, return `this.createLikertResponseGroup(result.likertResponseGroup)`

Comment: As a side advice in order to experiment with observables and learn, you can use StackBlitz for this. Or just go to `https://rxjs.dev/` and open the console, rxjs is loadded there. Just replace your actual API calls `dialogRef.afterClosed()` return some dummy Observable that you hardcode (potentially with some "setTimeout" to mimic asynchronicity), and many `console.log` to visualize the flow of the program.

Comment: i suggest you read this article :
https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/practical-rxjs-in-the-wild-requests-with-concatmap-vs-mergemap-vs-forkjoin-11e5b2efe293

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### `mergeMap` Instead of Nested `subscribe`

mergeMap does everything that a nested subscription does, but it also lets you continue your logic onward as it emits the subscribed values.

---

**Quick aside:**

> In cases where your subscribed observable emits once and completes (like an http request), `switchMap` and `mergeMap` produce the same output. `switchMap` is often recommended over `mergeMap` in these cases. The reasons range from debugging memory leaks, to marginal performance, to what other developers expect.
>
> For simplicity's sake, I've ignored that here and used `mergeMap` in all cases.

---

You can hide some complexity by nesting `mergeMap` and/or nesting `subscriptions` because you can rely on functional closures to set and remember values earlier in your pipeline.

It can also become a cause of great confusion down the line. Deeply nested functions are notoriously difficult to debug in JS so the extra effort of mapping into intermediate objects to hold the values you need in the next step (rather than nesting and getting intermediate values via functional closure) is well worth the effort.

It's also marginally faster as the runtime isn't required to travel up the call stack looking for variables (But again, you should do it because it's cleaner, maintainable, and extendable not in order to optimize early).

Here is your code litterally re-written with mergeMap and objects holding intermetiate values:

```js
dialogRef.afterClosed().pipe(
  filter(result => result), // <-- only "truthy" results pass same as if(result)
  mergeMap(result =>
    this.createLikertResponseGroup(result.likertResponseGroup).pipe(
      map(likertResponseGroupJSON => ({result, likertResponseGroupJSON}))
    )
  ),
  mergeMap(({result, likertResponseGroupJSON}) => merge(
    ...result.likertResponse.controls.likertResponseFormArray.controls.map(
      element => this.createLikertResponse(
        element, 
        likertResponseGroupJSON.LikertResponseGroup.id
      ).pipe(
        map(likertResponseJSON => ({
          likertResponseJSON,
          characteristic: element.controls.characteristic,
          newResponseGroupId: likertResponseGroupJSON.LikertResponseGroup.id
        }))
      )
    )
  )),
  filter(({characteristic}) => characteristic) // only "Truthy" characteristic allowed
  mergeMap(({likertResponseJSON, characteristic, newResponseGroupId}) =>
    this.createCharacteristic(
      characteristic, 
      newResponseGroupId, 
      likertResponseJSON.LikertResponse.id
    ).pipe(
      map(characteristicJSON => ({
        newCharacteristicId: characteristicJSON.Characteristic.id,
        newResponseGroupId
      }))
    )
  )
).subscribe(({newCharacteristicId, newResponseGroupId}) => {
  this.newResponseGroupId = newResponseGroupId;
  this.newCharacteristicId = newCharacteristicId;
});
```

#### `merge`/`forkJoin`/`concat` Instead of `forEach(stream.subscribe())`

You'll notice in the code above that when it came time to re-write your forEach loop, I used a combination of `merge` and `Array#map` instead of `Array#forEach`

`merge` is the closes equivalent to `forEach(stream.subscribe())`, but the others can change up behaviour in ways that may even boost performance or just allow you to compose more complex streams intuitively.

Here, lines 2 and 3 have identical output. The second one, however, is easily extended with more RxJS operators

```js
1. const arrayOfStreams = [s1,s2,s3,s4];
2. arrayOfStreams.forEach(s => s.subscribe(console.log));
3. merge(...arrayOfStreams).subscribe(console.log);
```

extending:

```js
arrayOfStreams.forEach(s => s.subscribe(value => {
  if(this.isGoodValue(value)){
    console.log(value.append(" end"))
  }
}));

merge(...arrayOfStreams).pipe(
  filter(this.isGoodValue),
  map(value => value.append(" end"))
).subscribe(console.log);
```

Comment: switchMap and mergeMap have significant differences in behavior and cooking this down to some hypothetical performance difference is misleading at best.

Comment: They're different in how they manage subscriptions to inner observables. In the cases where you can implement nested subscriptions via switchMap (cases where only one value is emitted and the stream completes), there is not any meaningful management of inner observables to be had - in that case there's basically no difference. Unless I'm missing something?

Comment: @IngoBürk I've updated my answer to sound less dismissive of the differences between `switchMap` and `mergeMap` without really going into any of the differences